# Recursively set Title property of all MP4 files based on filename in a folder and subfolders

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, mp4

I am looking for a way to set "Title" property of all MP4 files in a folder and subfolder based on the filename.

e.g. It should change the title of "Sample Video.mp4" file to "Sample Video", and similarly do this for all the files within the folder (from which the script is executed) and subfolders recursively.

I searched for ways to do this using ffmpeg and exiftool, but both the options need to make copy of the entire file to set this simple property, whereas Windows Explorer can do it very easily from the File Select -> right hand side details pane or File -> Properties -> Details. In both these options, it sets the file property in seconds without the need to copy the entire file.

Comment: take a look at MP3Tag. it has a `filename to tag` system that is quite easy to use. [*grin*] >>> Mp3tag - the universal Tag Editor (ID3v2, MP4, OGG, FLAC, ...) — https://www.mp3tag.de/en/

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Thank you so much. This is amazing and works for video MP4 and MKV files as well.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

You will need python, MKVtoolnix and Kid3-cli. Exif actually rewrites the file; this method just writes the metadata.  Leaps and bounds quicker.  Huge thanks to [Harvey at Github](https://github.com/HarveyDevel/rmeta)

Run this script from Python. I copy this file into the parent directory where I want the files to be edited.  Then within that parent directory, I go to the address bar and type `cmd` in the address bar, then type the command below to run the script.

`python remeta_mp4.py mp4` for the current directory only and `python remeta_mp4.py mp4 -r` to change all mp4 files in its subdirectories

Copy and save into notepad and ensure save as .py extension.

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os
import sys

def mp4_string(title):
    name, name_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(title).replace("'", "\\'"))
    return name

def exec_mp4(mp4name):
    mp4name_title = mp4_string(mp4name)
    subprocess.run(["kid3-cli", "-c", f"set title '{mp4name_title}'", mp4name], shell=True)

def mp4(recursive=False):
    if recursive:
        for mp4name in glob.glob('**/*.mp4', recursive=True):
            exec_mp4(mp4name)
            print(f"Title metadata of {mp4name} has been changed")
    else:
        for mp4name in glob.glob("*.mp4"):
            exec_mp4(mp4name)
            print(f"Title metadata of {mp4name} has been changed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: python rmeta.py mp4 [-r] for recursive operations")
        sys.exit(1)

    action_type = sys.argv[1]
    recursive = False
    if len(sys.argv) > 2 and sys.argv[2] == "-r":
        recursive = True

    if action_type == "mp4":
        mp4(recursive)
    else:
        print("Usage: python rmeta.py mp4 [-r] for recursive operations")
        sys.exit(1)
```

If you want to be able to double-click the .py file instead of using cmd prompt, you can use the below code. The code below will write ALL .mp4 files in the current AND subdirectories.  Just make sure you save it as .py file

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os
import sys

def mp4_string(title):
    name, name_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(title).replace("'", "\\'"))
    return name

def exec_mp4(mp4name):
    mp4name_title = mp4_string(mp4name)
    subprocess.run(["kid3-cli", "-c", f"set title '{mp4name_title}'", mp4name], shell=True)

def mp4(recursive=True):
    if recursive:
        for mp4name in glob.glob('**/*.mp4', recursive=True):
            exec_mp4(mp4name)
            print(f"Title metadata of {mp4name} has been changed")
    else:
        for mp4name in glob.glob("*.mp4"):
            exec_mp4(mp4name)
            print(f"Title metadata of {mp4name} has been changed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
mp4()
```